# Let $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i = 0$, how to prove $(\sum_{i = 1}^n a_i x_i^{2p-1})(\sum_{i=0}^n a_i x_i) \geq 0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

my question is that:

Let $a, b, x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ and $p \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, then whether the following inequality holds?
\begin{align}\label{eqn:1}
 (a x^{2p -1} + b y^{2p-1})( a x + b y) \geq 0, \quad p \geq 1
\end{align}

If it holds, how to prove it?

**EDIT2**

Sorry, I missed the condition $a + b = 0$.

The original problem reads:

Consier the first order differential operator $\partial_x$ in 1D interval $[0, 1]$ with periodical boundary condition. If I discretize $\partial_x$ using the Fourier pseudo-spetral method, then I get an skew-symmetric matirx $D_1 \in \mathbb{R^{N\times N}}$ , where $D_1^T = -D_1$ and the sum of each row equals $0$. Consider $V \in R^N$, then will the following inequality hold?
\begin{align}\label{eqn:2} 
(D V^{2p-1})^T (D V) \geq 1
\end{align}

The above statement does not hold.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am looking at your edited question. It is still false. Let me show with an example.

We need to check if the below inequality does not hold true for any subset.

$$\left(\sum_{i = 1}^n a_i x_i^{2p-1}\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i x_i\right) \geq 0$$
where
$$a_i, x_i \in \mathbb{R}, p \in \mathbb{Z}^+ \text{ and } \sum_{i=1}^n a_i = 0$$

Yes it is true for $n = 2$, but not for all $n$. Take this example:

$$n = 3, p=2, a_1 = 2, a_2 = 3, a_3=-5, x = 1, y=-3, z=-2$$
$$ \sum_{i=1}^3 a_i = 0$$
$$ \sum_{i=1}^3 a_i x_i = 3 \space \text{ and } \space \sum_{i=1}^3 a_i x_i^3 = -39$$
So,
$$\sum_{i=1}^3 a_i x_i \cdot \sum_{i=1}^3 a_i x_i^3 < 0$$

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for this counter example.

Answer (score 1):

Take $b=x=1,a=5,p=2,y=-3$ to get
$$(5-27)(5-3)\ge0$$
which is a contradiction.

**EDIT**
As asked by OP in comments, if the condition $a+b=0$ is added, then it becomes true, since
\begin{align*}
(ax^{2p-1}+by^{2p-1})(ax+by)&=a^2\Big(f(x)-f(y)\Big)(x-y)\ge0
\end{align*}
where $f(x)=x^{2p-1}$ is monotone function on $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Hi Martund, thank you very much. Another question, If I add one more condition $a + b = 0$, is that statement still false?

Comment: @skywalker, check out the edit.

Comment: Thank you Martund,  I updated the question,  could you please help me if it still be true?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The statement is false. Obviously it is true for $p=1$, so try the next nontrivial case: $p=2$.

Try it yourself. Only look at each hint (in order) if you're really still stuck.

> Hint: put some nontrivial numbers for $a $ and $ b $ and try finding a counterexample

> Can you make one bracket negative and the other bracket positive?

The next spoiler really is the whole answer!

> Try $a=1$ and $b=-2$

> Then if $x=ky$ then any $k \in (2^{1/3}, 2)$ works to give a counterexample.

Comment: Hi Benjamin,  thank you very much for your answer!  If the condition $a + b = 0$ is added, will the statement still be false?